# Nortel VPN, which ports must be open

Tags: vpn

I can connect to work using Nortel client VPN. To get it to work I need to open a set of ports in my firewall.

Anyone know which?

/Leif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to open any ports for the VPN client - it's all outgoing connections. You just need to make sure your router supports IPsec passthrough.

Comment: My router is a Linksys 45GL, on which I have installed OpenWRT. Therefore I configure the Linux firewall myself. So I guess getting IPsec passthough should be done "as normal". I'll keep searching on that. Thanks!